# I can't set compile Android version?

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I just made a fresh installation of Visual Studio 2015 which included Xamarin by default, on Windows 7 64 bit.

I downloaded all required software but I can't set compile version.

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know what can I do?

Comment: Did you follow the [installation guide steps](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/)?

Comment: Yes all of it..

Comment: not sure what you wanna achieve..
r u trying to Compile using a specific Android version? you can select Tools > Android > Android SDK Manager, and then install various APIs levels. Once installed what you need, you will be able to select the desired version, as stated in the first picture. (dont forget to restart VS ;-) )